# oozie subworkflow, real usecases

Tags: hadoop, oozie

what is the real use case of oozie sub-workflow ? i understood this allows to create an embedded workflow under another workflow. why we needed to do it in first place ?  Isnt there any alternative way in oozie that allows to have similar effect provided by sub workflows.

i am going through https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-shorten-your-oozie-workflow-definitions/ , it isnt that clear, do we really need sub-workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, The real use case is simple as we have to do a same action multiple times and we do not want to have the multiple actions in same xml file where only few parameters are changing. So we write that action in a separate xml file and we just include it (with `<sub-workflow>` tag) in workflow.xml with the customizable parameters.

Comment: Think also of a use case requiring FORK / JOIN with very complicated branches running in parallel. Without sub-workflows the resulting XML would be quite messy.

Comment: Ah, another use case: after the "main" actions you want to do some post-processing in *another* Hadoop cluster. Again, without a sub-workflow, the resulting XML would be quite messy.